# Azure Logic App - Manual trigger with user entered parameters

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've got a logic app that I want to be able to run ad hoc and specify the parameters when run.  The closest manual trigger i could find was the HTTP request.

As a workaround, I'm calling it from postman where the JSON body can be defined.

While postman works, I'm looking for a way to trigger the app from within azure and provide the JSON body.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are many way to trigger the logic app and process the json data.

You could try with service bus trigger or blob trigger, the below is my test with servicebus. I send a json message with Service bus Explorer. Note: in the logic app the json data is encoded with base64.

[image]

The below is the result.

[image]

However from the action you could find it has a Interval property to set, it means it may be not triggered immediately. And mostly other triggers need to set the Interval, so if you want to trigger immediately, suppose the HTTP request is the best.

Comment: Thank you George, I'll look into this as an option and post back my thoughts.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  We ended up having to go a different route - using a scheduled console application.  This was because the resources used in Azure are in a VNet which Logic cannot communicate with unless ISE is setup.  cost too much for our purpose.  Too bad really, this was cool/fun experiment.  Appreciate your time and effort @George Chen! Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

My workaround is a Recurrence trigger every 1 minute and let it kick off and then edit the trigger to every 1 month and save it.  Then I disable the Logic App to make sure it does not trigger automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).